# how to get nodes, which are not connected to x

Tags: gremlin

Given nodes v1 and v2, how to get nodes 't', in Gremlin, which are connected to v1 but not connected to v2.

t1 may also be connected to other nodes, besides v1, as long as it's not v2. I've tried to approach this with match:

```
g.V().match(
__.as_("a").hasId(v1_id).inE('follows').otherV().as_("t1"), 
__.as_("b").hasId(v2_id).inE('follows').otherV().as_("t2")
).where('t1', P.neq('t2')).select('t1')
```

but for some reason I get an error

{GremlinServerError}500: The provided match pattern is unsolvable: [[MatchStartStep(t1), WherePredicateStep(neq(t2)), MatchEndStep], [MatchStartStep(b), HasStep([~id.eq(1429616)]), JanusGraphVertexStep(IN,[follows],edge), EdgeOtherVertexStep, MatchEndStep(t2)], [MatchStartStep(a), HasStep([~id.eq(1388760)]), JanusGraphVertexStep(IN,[follows],edge), EdgeOtherVertexStep, MatchEndStep(t1)]]

The steps by themselves seems to be correct as they return t1/t2 as expected:

```
g.V().match(__.as_("a").hasId(v1_id).inE('follows').otherV().as_("t1"))
.select('t1')
```

I guess I don't quite understood how to use the conjunction of 2 matches - please advise.

[image]

Comment: what result are you expecting here? there is nothing in your diagram connected to v1 that is not connected to v2.

Comment: as if t1 not connected to v2 - this is why it's coloured in red. Assuming there are a lot of nodes 't' connected to nodes 'v'. Some of them connected both to v1 and v2, some of them only to v1 or v2 and some of them to neither of them. I want to get all the node 't', which are connected to v1 (and maybe other nodes), but NOT to v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all the `match()` complexity. Just start from `v1`, traverse to the `t`'s and verify that those `t`'s are not connected to `v2`.

```
g.V(v1_id).in("follows").not(out("follows").hasId(v2_id))
```